# Declaring dynamic object table

Tags: java

I got class Booking , and class Main. I want to use objects in class Main but i want to add new objects and delete objects during the program, is there any way to make it?
for example:

```
   class Main
  {
     private int d=0;
      private Booking[] book=new Booking[d];
     void main
     {
    d++;
  Booking[] book=new Booking[d]
  }
  }
```

Ive added list:

```
   private List<Object> list= new ArrayList<Object>();
```

now i want to acces to my objects:

```
            Booking book=new Booking();
            list.add(d, book);
            list.get(d).setYear(comboBox.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

but it doesnt work.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html  &   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like you need a table.
You can make semi-tables in Java using a Map (HashMap).
For instance, you can have a map of `<String,Object>` and store your objects there, represented by strings.

Comment: Then how to acces to these objects?

Comment: @B.M use the functions Map.put() for setting a value and Map.get() for getting a value